# C# Get Month INT from Month String

Tags: c#

I found a lot of ways to get the name from a number but now I need it the other way around.

If the string equals April, I want to convert it to int "4".

Does anyone know the best way to accomplish this server side?

Comment: Yeah I think it is. ::face palm::

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
int month = DateTime.ParseExact(MonthNameStr, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Month
```

or you can do

```
int  month = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames.ToList().IndexOf(MonthNameStr) + 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 int month = DateTime.ParseExact("April", "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;
```

Comment: ^^ the best way to get month number from month name or Code, so if you have "DEC" in string, you will use "MMM" in the second parameter. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with a custom format specifier consisting only of the the ["MMMM" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMMM_Specifier):

```
int month = DateTime.ParseExact("April", "MMMM", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
                    .Month;
```